# Rails controller is returning escaped JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

```
def show
    #find parent call_flow
    @call_flow = CallFlow.where('dnis' => params[:dnis]).first

    if @call_flow.nil?
        @response = ["no result"]
    else
        #find first routable options (should be a message)
        @call_flow_options = @call_flow.routable_type.constantize.find(@call_flow.routable_id).options

        #if there is a route after the first route, find it
        unless @call_flow_options.first.target_routable_type.nil?
            @target_routable = @call_flow_options.first.target_routable_type.constantize.find(@call_flow_options.first.target_routable_id).options
            @call_flow_options.to_a.push(@target_routable.to_a)
        end
        @response = @call_flow.to_a.push(@call_flow_options)
    end
    respond_with @response 

end
```

I get the data back but the browser doesn't recognize it as JSON because all the `"` double quotes are replaced with `&quot;`.

Comment: What does the problematic part of response look like?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/4501bb7379b6e4d91ba5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to have the entire response be JSON (rather than HTML/JavaScript that uses JSON) you can do:

```
render :json => @response
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't this is the real answer to the underlying problem, but it certainly works.